# Open a cmd from a Python script without (venv)

Tags: python, windows, cmd

With my Python script I just want to open a cmd window at a specific location. I do it like this:

```
subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe @cmd /k cd C:/PATH/TO/LOCATION", shell=True)
```

it works perfectly fine, but when the cmd is open, it always shows '(venv)' before the path in the cmd. Like this:

```
(venv) C:/PATH/TO/LOCATION>
```

So I assume that the cmd is started in a virtual environment? Why does this happen and how can I just open a cmd without (venv)?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Try `venv\scripts\deactivate` to deactivate virtual environment

Comment: Im using PyCharm community edition

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ where should I use `venv\scripts\deactivate` ?

Comment: In normal command line it will work but you are asking to do it via python rgt?

Comment: may be - subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe @cmd /k cd C:/PATH/TO/LOCATION; deactivate", shell=True)